# Subscripts in Emacs 24.4.1 not showing up properly

Tags: emacs, unicode, agda

I'm working on an assignment that used the unicode subscript k ("\_k"). However, instead of getting the subscripted k, I get this:

![][1]

The can still use subscripts with numbers and some letters, but not with 'k'.

I initially had the issue with emacs 24.3, and then was told to update to 24.4. The issue still persisted.

Has anyone else had this issue and found a solution?

I'm running on a Mac with Emacs v.24.4.1

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is my .emacs file:

```
(load-file (let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8))
             (shell-command-to-string "agda-mode locate")))

(set-default-font "-apple-DejaVu_Sans-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1")
; Change Control-c Control-, and Control-c Control-. in Agda mode
; so they show the normalized rather than the "simplified" goals
(defun agda2-normalized-goal-and-context ()
  (interactive)
  (agda2-goal-and-context '(3)))
(defun agda2-normalized-goal-and-context-and-inferred ()
  (interactive)
  (agda2-goal-and-context-and-inferred '(3)))
(eval-after-load "agda2-mode"
  '(progn
     (define-key agda2-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-,")
       'agda2-normalized-goal-and-context)
     (define-key agda2-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-.")
       'agda2-normalized-goal-and-context-and-inferred)))

; This defines backslash commands for some extra symbols.
(eval-after-load "quail/latin-ltx"
  '(mapc (lambda (pair)
           (quail-defrule (car pair) (cadr pair) "TeX"))
         '( ("\\bb" "") ("\\bl" "") ("\\bs" "")
            ("\\bt" "") ("\\bv" "") ("\\cv" "⋎")
            ("\\comp" "∘") ("\\m" "↦") ("\\om" "ω"))))

; This sets the Control-c Control-k shortcut to
; describe the character under your cursor.
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-k" 'describe-char)

(custom-set-variables
 '(agda2-include-dirs
   (quote ("." "/Users/dylanthiemann/Dropbox/University of Iowa/2nd Senior Year/Spring 2015/PLC/ial")))
 )
```

And the bit of code is from Agda:

```
module bool-kleene-thms where

open import bool
open import bool-kleene
open import eq

&&ₖ-idem : ∀ (b : ₖ) → b &&ₖ b ≡ b
&&ₖ-idem b = {!!}

tt-&&ₖ : ∀ (b : ₖ) → tt &&ₖ b ≡ b
tt-&&ₖ b = {!!}

||ₖ-idem : ∀ (b : ₖ) → b ||ₖ b ≡ b
||ₖ-idem b = {!!}

||ₖ-tt : ∀ (b : ₖ) → b ||ₖ tt ≡ tt
||ₖ-tt b = {!!}

||ₖ-ff : ∀ (b : ₖ) → b ||ₖ ff ≡ b
||ₖ-ff b = {!!}
```

**Edit 2**

Results of `Ctrl-u Ctrl-x =` on affected character:

```
             position: 91 of 830 (11%), column: 2
            character: ₖ (displayed as ₖ) (codepoint 8342, #o20226, #x2096)
    preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2096
               script: symbol
               syntax: w        which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong)
             to input: type "\_k" with Agda input method
          buffer code: #xE2 #x82 #x96
            file code: #xE2 #x82 #x96 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: terminal code #xE2 #x82 #x96
```

Comment: Normally I would suspect a fonts issue. Try switching to a font with decent Unicode coverage like DejaVu Sans Mono and see if that helps. (In this case I see that you have glyphs for some other interesting characters, so you may already be using an appropriate font.)

Comment: This is the current font I'm using (found in .emacs) 

`(set-default-font "-apple-DejaVu_Sans-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1")`

Comment: I think we're going to need more information. What major mode are you using? Could you paste the raw code into your question in addition to the rendered screenshot?

Comment: I added my .emacs file as well as a bit of the code I showed above

Comment: Oh, wow. This language uses Unicode natively, eh? With point on one of the problematic `ₖ` characters, can you run `C-u C-x =`? You should get a bunch of information, including something like `character: ₖ (displayed as ₖ) (codepoint 8342, #o20226, #x2096)`.

Comment: Yeah Agda is a 'fun' language. Added the results above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69692/discussion-between-chris-and-tad).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to install new fonts... I used this http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download and then installed using Font Books. The issue was then resolved!

Comment: thanks, this fix worked for me. A bit surprising because I didn't need to change the font I was using (menlo I believe). Since this was written the page for dejavu fonts has moved to https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/